# IF Clause usage in Select Query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to use IF statement in SELECT Query. Here is the sample for that.
I have 3 table which keeps customer info, and models info, and stocks. I want to offer best fit model to each individual customer. So in my first try if customer income less then 5000 i want to offer cheap models that exist in that store, else any model in that store.
But i couldnt use IF clouse in SELECT WHERE section.

```
SELECT  TOP 1 @vmodel  = stocks.model , @vsloc = stocks.sloc , @vyear = models.year , @vcost = models.cost <br>FROM bistore.dbo.stocks 
JOIN bistore.dbo.models
ON stocks.model = models.model 
WHERE stocks.sloc<>'Main'
AND stocks.stock > 0 
AND models.mat IN (
IF (@vincome<5000) SELECT DISTINCT mat from models where mat<>'Carbon' 
ELSE SELECT DISTINCT mat from models 
)   /* If income is less than 5000 than chose cheap models , else whatever ) */
```

** UPDATE ** 
When a customer login to my portal i want to offer him/her best model fits to him. I will check his income, store stock close to him and offer him in banner. Here is my samples from tables.

[CustomerInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6aVB.jpg)

[ModelInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yubPW.jpg)

DECLARE @vcname   VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @vckids   INT
DECLARE @vcleng   INT
DECLARE @vcweig   INT
DECLARE @vcincome INT
DECLARE @vyear    INT
DECLARE @vcost    INT

SELECT TOP 1  @vcname  = nmsnm ,  @vckids = kids ,  @vcleng = leng, @vcweig = weig , @vcincome = income FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC


DECLARE @vmodel  VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @vsloc   VARCHAR(50)
SELECT  TOP 1 @vmodel  = stocks.model , @vsloc = stocks.sloc , @vyear = models.year , @vcost = models.cost FROM bistore.dbo.stocks 
  JOIN bistore.dbo.models 
  ON stocks.model = models.model 
  WHERE stocks.sloc<>'Main' 
    AND stocks.stock > 0 
    AND models.mat IN ( 
        IF (@vincome<5000) BEGIN SELECT DISTINCT mat from models where mat<>'Carbon' END 
        ELSE BEGIN SELECT DISTINCT mat from models END 
        )   /* If income is less than 5000 than chose cheap models , else whatever ) */ 

    AND models.frames IN (SELECT frames from models where frames<48) /* chose model fit to length */ 
 
    AND models.type <> 'Kids Bike'                                   /* if have kids , chose whatever (not bigger then length)  */ 
ORDER BY NEWID()

Comment: can you give us some sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `IF` or `CASE`, just an additional `AND` and a reversed `@vincome` check:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
       @vmodel = stocks.model , 
       @vsloc =  stocks.sloc , 
       @vyear =  models.year , 
       @vcost = models.cost <br> 
FROM   bistore.dbo.stocks 
JOIN   bistore.dbo.models 
ON     stocks.model = models.model 
WHERE  stocks.sloc <>'Main' 
AND    stocks.stock > 0 
AND ( @vincome >= 5000 OR models.mat <> 'Carbon' )
```

You see that you don't even need a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL it is the CASE statement of which details are [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

A possible usage (please refer your objects for correct syntax):

```
SELECT  TOP 1 @vmodel  = stocks.model , @vsloc = stocks.sloc , @vyear = models.year , @vcost = models.cost <br>FROM bistore.dbo.stocks 
JOIN bistore.dbo.models
ON stocks.model = models.model 
WHERE stocks.sloc<>'Main'
AND stocks.stock > 0 
AND models.mat IN (
    CASE sign(@vincome - 5000)
       WHEN -1 then (SELECT DISTINCT mat from models where mat<>'Carbon')
       ELSE '(SELECT DISTINCT mat from models ) 
    END
    )   /* If income is less than 5000 than chose cheap models , else whatever ) */
```

PS: Sign is a trick I use to mimic greater / equal / smaller control for better comprehension of CASE syntax.